# Fetch Azure Organization by Subscription Id

Tags: azure, rest, go, sdk, organization

Using the Azure Golang ARM SDK, I am able to fetch all resources under a subscription, except for the Azure Organization.

Is there a REST API, or Golang library that allows to programmatically fetch the Azure Organization with which the subscription is associated?
Note that the only parameter I can provide is the Subscription Id.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

I created an Application by granting **API permission** like below:

[image]

I generated the access token using below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/cdf429fe-37a2-4a79-8e40-7adbac3f8552/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_secret: client_secret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://management.azure.com/.default
client_id:18e97655-fba5-4644-8abc-XXXXXXX
```

[image]

**To fetch the all the Azure AD B2C tenant resources in a subscription, try the below command:**

```json
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories?api-version=2021-04-01
```

[image]

**To fetch Azure Organization by Subscription Id, try the below command:**

```json
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Confluent/organizations?api-version=2021-12-01
```

[image]